# Postgresql where clause return wrong results

Tags: postgresql

I would get theses datas :

- "roads" between 1156 (end_buffer) and 1296 (start_point)
- others datas like "Town" or "Discoveries" between 1156 (end_buffer) and 1296 (start_buffer)

```
   WHERE
   ( destination.poitable_type <> 'Road' 
     AND destination_to_paris > origin.end_buffer AND destination_to_paris < origin.start_buffer
   OR
     destination.poitable_type = 'Road'
     AND destination_to_paris  BETWEEN origin.start_buffer AND origin.start_point             
    )
```

But the first two results are wrong

| poitable_type | start_point | start_buffer | end_buffer | destination_to_paris |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "Road" | 1296 | 1196 | 1156 | 1498 |
| "Road" | 1296 | 1196 | 1156 | 1396 |
| "Road" | 1296 | 1196 | 1156 | 1280 |
| "Town" | 1296 | 1196 | 1156 | 1256 |
| "Discoveries" | 1296 | 1196 | 1156 | 1246 |

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Sorry, it's not the good tag. I'm using PostgreSQL 14.4

Comment: Can't reproduce.  Can you produce a db-fiddle or something showing this?